# Read PHP string from a MySql row with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, variables

I have a very large MySql table: over 900 rows of different sentences. I would like to put `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname')?>` in some of my rows. For example in:

```
Continue tes efforts <?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname')?> et imagine si tes travaux étaient toujours bien faits!`
```

And in my view, when I do `echo $data['sentence']` I would like to get

```
Continue tes efforts ***ROGER*** et imagine si tes travaux étaient toujours bien faits!
```

I need to split the sentence in my database `( id , part1 , part 2 )` (I need to "cut" my sentence in my database row when I need to get `FIRSTNAME`)  and here is what I do:

```
echo $data['part1'];
echo $this->session->userdata('firstname');
echo $data['part2'];
```

So, I would like to know if is it possible to put some PHP inside a MySql table  and read it from a echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use printf or sprintf for such things:

```
$string = "Continue tes efforts %s et imagine si tes travaux étaient toujours bien faits!";
printf($string, $this->session->userdata('firstname');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want, is a string in the database, that contains a placeholder for the name.

Besides sprintf.

What you can do, is put a codename for your variable in your sentence.
So your sentence will look like this:

Now you can do a simple str_replace on the string, replacing *|firstname|* with $this->session->userdata('firstname')

This way you can also add different type of variables to the string, and simply write a function that replaces every codename with the correct value.

Comment: you know s/printf can do this and more ?

Comment: I don't know if s/printf can replace these kind of codenames or tags or how you like to call them. I always thought that s/printf was pretty much order based, so the first parameter you send, will be replace the first specifier.
If not, i'd love to see an example! always nice to learn some new tricks ;-)

Comment: `<?php
$format = 'On the %2$s are sitting %1$d Aps';
printf($format, $count, $location);
?>
` see http://uk.php.net/sprintf for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Continue tes efforts %s et imagine si tes travaux étaient toujours bien faits!";
echo sprintf($string, $this->session->userdata('firstname'));
```

That should work! :)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a place holder eg:

```
Continue tes efforts <%FIRSTNAME%> et imagine si tes travaux étaient toujours bien faits!
```

Then when echoing out:

```
echo str_replace('<%FIRSTNAME%>',$this->session->userdata('firstname'),$data['sentence']);
```

Also remember arrays can be passed to str_replace() so multiple values can be swapped.